# Is it possible to hide tag based on condition in pure HTML?

Tags: html

I have one condition. Upon which I want to display that tag. In angular ngIf is there. But, in pure HTML is there any attribute?

I tried

hidden

hidden="false"

hidden="true"

but, nothing is working.

Comment: ```if (myCondition) {
  document.getElementById('myElement').style.hidden = "true"; 
}``` where you set id="myElement" on your tag.

Comment: It is not possible in pure HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure HTML/CSS has "display" settings:

```html
<div style="display:none">
<p>This graf will not appear.</p>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="display:block">
<p>This graf will appear normally.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with just pure CSS or vanilla JavaScript. If you are using the JS, you just need to target the selector and then either add a class or remove a class to toggle the visibility

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the `hidden` attribute to toggle the visibility of an element:

```js
const toggle = document.querySelector('#toggle');
const content = document.querySelector('#content');

toggle.addEventListener('click', event => {
  content.toggleAttribute('hidden');
});
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Toggle hidden attribute</button>
<div id="content" hidden>Some content with a hidden attribute.</div>
```

You can also use the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) functions if a toggle is not a good solution for you.

Comment: Thing is I am using backend mail service, so the template is of HTML. user8356 's solution is basic